# Delete files in directory without having to wait for whole list

Tags: powershell

I have a large number F of files to sort through (5M+) and want to delete everything older than N days.

Is there any way of starting to delete files before the whole set has been identified -- perhaps equivalent to

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo($folder).EnumerateFiles( ... )
```

in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Get-ChildItem already does this. Files are passed down the pipes as soon as they are processed. Try this;

```
$NDays = -5
dir *.* | where{$_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays($NDays)} | Remove-Item
```

Comment: I don't think get-childitem has a -files option? otherwise tho' looks good, thanks.

Comment: Sadly I'm using powershell 2.0 -- but it looks like I can add where {$_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays($NDays) -and ! $_.PSIsContainer} to specify files

Comment: If you don't have any sub-directories that you have to exclude, you could just skip checking for the type all together. But if you do, then I think the most efficient way would be to use -Filter; `dir *.* | ...` The -Filter parameter is passed to the PSProvider so non-matches are never passed to the PowerShell engine in the first place.